# Get inventory from quickbooks and update to ecommerce platform

Tags: quickbooks

We are using Quickbooks desktop enterprise version and we are integrating quickbooks desktop with online ecommerce store.

I am looking for solution where are I get the updated inventory data and updated those data in ecommerce solution.

SO for that I want some solution that how can I get the data through web connector to my SOAP API and updated them in store?

I am not able to find out any API solution for that. Please help us.

Comment: What programming language? What have you tried so far? Did you read through the literally hundreds of pages available on this exact topic, from the QuickBooks website?

Comment: I am implementing it in PHP. I have implemented syncronizes data from my ecommerce to Quickbooks. So customer, products are updated from ecommerce to quickbooks. I need to understand that, how can i get updated data from quicbooks to ecommerce store.

Comment: Cool. Post the code that you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

And follow the quick-start guide:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php#quick-start-guides

In the docs you'll find examples of pulling data back from QuickBooks, into your app. Specifically, this one:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/web_connector/example_web_connector_import.php

You'll have to make some changes to instead issue a report query to get inventory stock status per item. Your query/function to do that is going to look something like this:

```
    function _inventoryStockStatusByItemRequest($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
    {
        $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <?qbxml version="8.0"?>
            <QBXML>
                <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                    <GeneralSummaryReportQueryRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">

                        <GeneralSummaryReportType>InventoryStockStatusByItem</GeneralSummaryReportType>
                        <DisplayReport>false</DisplayReport>

                    </GeneralSummaryReportQueryRq>
                </QBXMLMsgsRq>
            </QBXML>';

        return $xml;
    }
```

That will get you back a gigantic XML document with the quantities on hand of every product.

You can then parse that XML document and do whatever you need with it.

Comment: How can i get started with your solution ? What is the entry point ? Means what tables needs to create etc ?

Comment: Did you go through the quick-start? It walks you through all of this.

Comment: What will be the quickbooks SOAP server class which need to defined as AppUrl? Will it be QuickBooks/WebConnector/Server.php ?

Comment: No. Point the Web Connector to the example_web_connector.php script (or whatever you renamed that to).